# How do I show the simulations inside the code printing the array for each search session and printing the total comparison at last?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, binary-search, recurrence

Implement the recursive version of Binary Search. Simulate and show all the
steps using code. Also show number of comparisons and basic operations in code.
Sample Input:
2,3,5,8,12,34,44,55,77,88,99,123

Search 5

Output:

1st iteration: 2,3,5,8,12,34,44,55,77,88,99,123

2nd iteration: 2,3,5,8,12

Found at 5

Total comparisons: 2

Total operations: ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int count=0;
int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high, int x)
{
    while (high >= low)
    {
        count=count++;
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        count=count+3;
        if (arr[mid] == x)
        {
            count=count+2;
            return mid;
        }
        if (arr[mid] >x)
        {
            count=count+2;
            return binarySearch(arr,low,mid-1,x);
        }
        else
        {
           return binarySearch(arr,mid+1,high,x);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n,i;

    int high,low;
    cout << "Enter n:";//array size
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    cout << "Enter the numbers ";//array size

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];//array elements
    }

    int x;
    cout << "Enter the number you want to search";
    cin >> x;

    int result = binarySearch(arr, 0, n-1, x);
    (result == -1) ? cout << "Element is not present in array"
                   : cout << "Element is present at index " << result;
    cout << "count " << count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem that you experience?

Comment: You have asked already a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63026988/how-do-i-print-the-array-at-a-time-its-searching-the-element-in. What's the difference?

Comment: General advice: keep your code clearly formatted. That would simplify both your work and the other's.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I don't know how can I print the remaining array for each iteration.

Comment: What the "remaining array" is? Do you mean the range [low, high]?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I edited the question, The output should be shown like that after I search an element

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is "how to print the array in the range [low, high]", you may insert this:

```
for (int i = low; i <= high; ++i) {
    cout << (i == low? "": ",") << arr[i];
}
```

I would advise you to refactor your code exclude the upper margin however, as this is easear to work with. That would mean that the range is [low, high). The first call would be `binarySearch(arr, 0, n, x)` in this case.